# 'chromedriver_mac' executable needs to be in PATH

Tags: python, macos, selenium, webdriver

I am trying to create a web scraper with Selenium module. The user has a Mac system. My project folder consist of

```
./scraper    The main file
   ./lib     The folder where chromedriver_mac is placed
   ./src     py file is here
```

So, I used os.chdir() to go back one folder and then find the "lib" folder.

```
os.chdir("..")
os.chdir("lib")
browser = webdriver.Chrome("chromedriver_mac")
```

It works perfectly on Windows. However, when it comes to MAC, it throws exception.

```
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'chromedriver_mac'
.
.

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
.
.
WebDriverException(selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: 'chromedriver_mac' executable needs to be in PATH.
```

I need to find a solution that will use relative path. Absolute paths doesn't look like a solution to me since there will be different users.

Thank you.

Comment: Have you tried calling `browser = webdriver.Chrome("../lib/chromedriver_mac")`? Not that it's any different logically from what you're doing, but OS differences can be painfully annoying and this should work universally.

Comment: @ABear It didnt work. When I put the location absolute as "/Users/xxx/Downloads/chromedriver", it strangely works. I am really lost.

Comment: Is it in Downloads or is it in ../lib?

Answer (score 0):

Try to use:

```
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
```

To install it:

```
pip3 install webdriver-manager
```

Then you can call:

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager().install())
```

This remove the need to always download the chrome driver to match your chrome version and having to provide the path (which is the issue here).
It will do a validation and install (if needed) the right one each time you launch your code.

More info about this package [here](https://pypi.org/project/webdriver-manager/)